# Inverse result for Direct sum of vector space theorem

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

From direct sum of vector space, we know that given a vector space $V$ and subspaces $U$ and W, if $V= U+W$, and $U\cap W = \{0\}$, then $V= U \oplus W$. My question is given a vector space $V$ which can be expressed as direct sum of $U$ and $W$ i.e. $V= U \oplus W$, then can we say that $U\cap W = \{0\}$ will always be true. Why or why not? prove the result or give a counter example.

Comment: The notation $V=U\oplus W$ means, by *definition*, that $V=U+W$ and $U\cap W=\{0\}$.

Comment: I don't think so, this is the theorem that specifies when the sum is a direct sum. The basic definition of direct sum is any $v1 \in V$ can be expressed as a sum of unique elements $u1 \in U $ and $w1 \in W$.

Comment: I'm sorry. I assumed everyone used the same definition as me (my fault).

Comment: I would like to ask, can we replace any definition by a theorem that correspond to that definition? Why or why not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. This is true in general. If $v\in U\cap W$, then $-v\in W$, and hence, $0=v+(-v)\in U\oplus W=V$. Since the representation of $0$ as a sum of vectors in $U$ and $W$ is unique, we must have $v=0$. I.e., $U\cap W=\{0\}$.

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on your definition of the direct sum: If the direct sum $V=U\oplus W$ is that $V=U+W$ and $U\cap V=\{0\}$ then we have nothing to prove. It's possible to define the direct sum $V=U\oplus W$ in this way: for every $v\in V$, there is unique $(u,w)\in U\times W$ such that $v=u+w$. in this case to prove that $U\cap W=\{0\}$ notice that if $x\in U\cap W$ then $0=x+(-x)=0+0\in U+W$ so by unicity we get $x=0$.

Comment: I don't think that the direct sum is defined  as $V=U \oplus W $ and $ U \cap V={0}$. This is a theorem so it is not a definition of the direct sum. Though the argument given after the statement seems to answer the question.

Comment: The two definitions are equivalent so if you take one as definition the other would be a consequence.

Comment: Since you have raised this issue, I would like to ask, can we replace any definition by a theorem that correspond to that definition? Why or why not?

Comment: We can replace any statement by an equivalent statement. What statement would choose as definition? I think it should be the statement nearest to the intuition.